# Does holding information in a Factory instead of passing it through calling code make sense?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a factory which creates objects that are widely used through my application.  Some of the objects the factory creates require another dependency.  This optional dependency is an interface/class with settings from a local settings file.  Currently both the factory interface AND the settings interface are injected into something like 20 classes.  Albeit, the number of classes would be less if the applications inheritance tree wasn't about 6-7 levels deep (meaning the IFactory and ISettings get passed through 6 constructors and finally arrive at a base class which assigns them to a field).

The deep inheritance isn't getting changed anytime soon, but I thought that I could lessen the load of these constructors by removing the ISettings from them and putting it in the IFactory implementation itself.  The ISettings would be injected into the concrete factory through the constructor, and then instead of passing the ISettings as a part of the Create() method, it would just use the factory ISettings readonly property.  These settings are guaranteed to be immutable once the program starts.

Is this frowned upon in any way, and are there better ways of going about this?  Some coworkers think that Factories should almost never hold state...but they aren't exactly sure why.

These are similar questions that I found, that gave answers but I'm still looking for a more fleshed out answer if possible.

[Adding Properties to Abstract Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996436/adding-properties-to-abstract-factory)

[Abstract Factory Pattern and Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681952/abstract-factory-pattern-and-properties)

Simple example:

```
interface IObjValidator
{
    bool Validate();
}

interface IObjValidatorFactory
{
    IObjValidator Create();
}

class ObjValidatorFactory : IObjValidatorFactory
{
    // Is it OK for the factory to hold this field?
    private readonly ISettings settings;    

    public IObjValidator(ISettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }    

    IObjValidator Create(ObjValidatorMode mode)
    {
        switch(mode)
        {
             case ObjValidatorMode.One:
                 return ObjValidator1();

             case ObjValidatorMode.Two:
                 return ObjValidator2(this.settings);
        }
    }
}

class ObjValidator1: IObjValidator
{
    public bool Validate()
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}

class ObjValidator2: IObjValidator
{
    private readonly ISettings settings;

    public ObjValidator2(ISettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        // Use ISettings field data here.            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this frowned upon in any way, and are there better ways of going about this?

An **incorrect** approach to solving this problem would be to have a *Singlteon* settings class that the validators access using `Settings.getInstance`. This is what would be frowned upon. The approach mentioned in the question actually tackles all the issues that a singleton settings class would have introduced and is is therefore the right way forward.

That said, one thing I would change is that I would make the `ObjValidatorFactory` class depend on an `ISettingsFactory` interface rather than depending on `ISettings` directly. This would redirect the responsibility of creating an `ISettings` implementation from the client class to `ObjValidatorFactory`.

```
class ObjValidatorFactory: IObjValidatorFactory
{
    private ISettingsFactory settingsFactory;

    public ObjValidatorFactory(ISettingsFactory settingsFactory)
    {
        this.settingsFactory = settingsFactory;
    }

    IObjValidator Create(ObjValidatorMode mode)
    {
        //source could be the file name for example
        ISettings settings = settingsFactory.Create(source);
        switch(mode)
        {
             case ObjValidatorMode.One:
                 return ObjValidator1();

             case ObjValidatorMode.Two:
                 return ObjValidator2(settings);
        }
    }


}
```

The factory could be instantiated as follows :

```
ISettingsFactory fileSettingsFactory = new FileSettingsFactory();
IObjValidatorFactory objectValidatorFactory = new ObjValidatorFactory(fileSettingsFactory);
objectValidatorFactory.Create(ObjValidatorMode.STRICT);
```

Comment: Well explained answer and I agree with everything except this:  The Settings Factory seems like overkill (in my case) since there will only ever be one Settings which is created at the start of the application session and passed to the ObjValidatorFactory.  I just can't think of a benefit, but I welcome being told why I'm wrong.

Comment: @user2079828 The presence of an `ISettings` interface indicates that you might have multiple implementations of settings in the future that can be loaded form different sources (file, database, etc). If that is not the case, then you could do away with `ISettingsFactory` and directly create an instance of `Settings` in the `Create` method of `ObjectValidatorFactory` for example.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see why you suggested that now.  I believe that ISettings was created solely for the purpose of Mocking.  I now agree that putting the creation of the Settings in the Factory, as you pointed out, is the best idea.

Comment: Another change you could consider is to make `IObjValidatorFactory` an abstract class and let it initialize a `protected` settings instance variable. The concrete factories can then access the settings from this parent rather than instantiating it independently.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather avoid that if I could, everything else being equal, if ObjValidator2 was somehow replaced with a different validator (e.g. ObjValidator2a),

A.) you would now have to change your constructor to accept a settings object for objValidator2a 
B.) drop it from the constructor because objValidator2a does not need settings for objValidator2
C.) keep the constructor as is knowing that the setting passed will never be used.

YMMV

Comment: The chances of 'A' are almost nonexistant in this codebase, but would that be so bad?  The factory would now hold two settings files instead of 'again' injecting another object through 20 classes for almost no reason.  For C, it's definitely an optional dependency to the Factory, but I'm inclined to like that over having that optional dependency in 20 other classes.  Thoughts?

Comment: CKings answer looks good. Another approach if you have control over the sourcecode of the object validators is to remove the settings loading on the constructor and create another interface method to load the settings (e.g. void LoadSettings(Settings settings) ) and have a SettingsLoader class has a single responsibility of calling the LoadSettings method of the created instances. Just pick whichever feels like a "more natural fit" for your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Few observations:
- Not all validators require ISettings
- Object is created based on mode

In this case, I think that Abstract factory suits more, delegating responsibilities to child classes.

It is ok to have fields in Factory class which will be responsible for factoring the same object, think of a biscuit factory always creating a same biscuit.

The way, you have defined the factory class, can lead to content coupling. In future, you will start injecting more and more dependencies which will not be maintainable.

Another way could be to inject the pre-built validators as a map in the factory and on create() , get an entry from the map.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean with "inject the pre-built validators as a map in the factory...".  Also, the Validators are almost all finished, there is little chance of more types being created, but even if there were more Validators in the future wouldn't putting other static and immutable data into the factory be be better than injecting even more things into 20 other classes?  It feels much more maintainable and readable.